# Run a Bash Script on New User Creation by SSSD

Tags: linux, active-directory, bash, sssd, adduser

Users created on AD can login to Linux with a password. I would like to replace this password login with ssh-key. So far, I've made a custom attribute and placed the public key in it and able to fetch it on Linux with a script. I would like to put this key in the /home/user/.ssh/authorised_key whenever a  new user is created.

Is there an event or some config file that I can use to trigger my script?

Note: SSSD is creating the user and home directory whenever a user login for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than copying the public key from your Active Directory to a `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file you can configure openssh to directly validate against AD instead.

OpenSSH supports the [`AuthorizedKeysCommand`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#AuthorizedKeysCommand) directive for your `sshd_config` that allows you to **specify a program to be used to look up the user's public key** instead before attempting to reading it from a (local) file. For instance:

```
 AuthorizedKeysCommand /path/to/script %u
```

where `/path/to/script` takes a for example username as a commandline argument and which then on standard output must return zero or more lines of authorized_keys output.

Comment: That is a nice way of implementing this. But I'm not sure how to provide the username to the script.
AuthorizedKeysCommand /root/script.sh

In the script.sh, I've to provide the username against which I'll fetch the ssh key.

Comment: The SSH daemon provides the expansion of `%u` (and other % variables) and will call your script with the username the ssh client attempting to log in provides. You have to create/ modify your script to take a username as a commandline argument , in a bash script something like `./script -u USERNAME`  and then in the script use something like `getopts` to parse the commandline argument to make a username available in your script for further processing

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I've followed your instructions and I'm getting this error :

Mar 26 12:07:08 key-test sshd[14967]: error: AuthorizedKeysCommand /var/local/ssh_gen.sh harry failed, status 1

Comment: while running the script manually gives me the key :
[root@key-test local]# /var/local/ssh_gen.sh harry >
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAlabPqn5b2u8q/RdSA4fb85076dTfM3zf4KIPXYcVhGevG/HR//ft0oMMqEEYSjvCr75cd95G6TTbdHbxMUfm26gmNN8EdsMCSpM0gJid8wOSGqmjZcaBgu7GMWdSSoRhkAQJtIvToiwHDSkgU2Am7miL/VIvePlW6c/3RSclKfJtHUG8yWF4EBUhhydVKIUiQMM2KlZJGx6FN2P6RoWJYVRNmN502yqk2p1uNQ5GfbUgBoIQ7DlBUbvbhdksz0QE8NlJqB0g1iuCC4FqgUlFpasEhldci0VBsRbl65jYknhVl6/yHzfXOTCjVIXOIqvvMKU8HGHfBr1+nQWrsDpE3Q== rsa-key-20190322

Comment: The permissions on the script are : -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 404 Mar 26 12:05 ssh_gen.sh

Comment: And the sshd_config file is set as this: AuthorizedKeysCommand /var/local/ssh_gen.sh %u
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody